# Whats the easiest way to change a class within a Python-library

Tags: python

lets assume i want to modify a Python module. And i want to change one class of this module.
How would you do that?

I have 2 options in my mind.

1. i could download the source code of the library and adapt it. And instead of using the library i now use my own adapted code. However the problem with this one is: Am not using the library anymore and if there are bugfixes or updates, i will have to merge my own code again
2. the second option i have in mind is to write a class which extends this library class i want to change. But i think this would be even harder to do: The class i want to change is not the class i am using directly in my code. It is a sub-sub-sub-....-sub class of it. So again i would have to recreate nearly half of the library.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The reason behind doing it in the first place can motivate a solution.

Comment: Your second option is just repeating the first option every single time you run your code. Without further details, I would suggest that you just accept that you want to fork the library.